# How to get value of synclient parameter?

Tags: command-line, 22.04, shortcuts

`synclient` enables you to change its parameters' values, e.g.:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Is there a possibility to access the value, print it, for instance?

I'd like to be able to set a value depending on the current value, e.g.:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=abs($TouchpadOff.value - 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out an answer thank to [@user.dz answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1465363/1120042):

```bash
touchpadoff_value=$(synclient -l | awk '$1=="TouchpadOff" {print $(NF)}'); (( tmp_value =  $touchpadoff_value - 1 )); synclient TouchpadOff=${tmp_value#-}
```

- to obtain `TouchpadOff` value:

```bash
$(synclient -l | awk '$1=="TouchpadOff" {print $(NF)}')
```

- to get absolute value of `tmp_value`:

```
${tmp_value#-}
```

Answer (score 2):

`synclient` or `synclient -l` then cut it from there.

```
toggle_value=$(synclient -l | awk '$1=="TouchpadOff" {print 2-$(NF)}')
synclient TouchpadOff=$toggle_value
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @maciejwww could you add output of `synclient -l` to the question? Do `synclient TouchpadOff=1` & `synclient TouchpadOff=0` works as direct commands?

Comment: Yes, they work.

Comment: @maciejwww probably missed `echo` in first command, updated the answer

Comment: You probably want `toggle_value=$(echo "1 - $(synclient -l | awk '$1=="TouchpadOff" {printf "%d", $(NF)}')" | bc)` ... Also I think you can do the arithmetic in bash without `bc`